# Replace a string using sed

Tags: linux, sed

I want to replace a string `ip_ttl="1"` with `ip_ttl="2"` using `sed`.

I've tried `sed -i "s/ip_ttl="1"/ip_ttl="2"/g"` - but its not working.

Please help!

Comment: Would fit best at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If you do that you are opening and closing the thing twice. You have to use a different type of quotation marks

Comment: @mins This question could be here since it is coding (source of code) problem not simply a unix problem (even if the real problem is a shell interpretation in this case, know from the OP only when solution is provided)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your sed code inside single quotes, because your code already contains  double quotes.

```
sed -i 's/ip_ttl="1"/ip_ttl="2"/g' file
```

If you put your code within  two double quotes, sed would terminate the program once another double quote was reached. So `"` before `1` was reached, it would consider as the end and terminates the program.

**Update:**

If the number always changes then it's better to define the pattern which matches any number.

```
sed -i 's/ip_ttl="[0-9]\+"/ip_ttl="2"/g' file
```

Comment: one more thing ip_ttl="1" will get changed from 1 to 0 or any number - should replace with ip_ttl="2"

Answer (score 1):

If you are using quotation marks in your pattern either escape double quotes in pattern:

```
sed -i "s/ip_ttl=\"1\"/ip_ttl=\"2\"/g"
```

or enclose whole pattern in single quotes:

```
sed -i 's/ip_ttl="1"/ip_ttl="2"/g'
```

Comment: we have one more problem - trying to replace timeToLive=99(dynamic value it it) with timeToLive=0 from the file , the format sed -i 's/timeToLive=*/timeToLive=0/g' is not replacing properly, please suggest

Comment: sed -i 's/timeToLive=[0-9]\+/timeToLive=0/g'

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can escape the quotation marks

```
sed -i "s/ip_ttl=\"1\"/ip_ttl=\"2\"/g" file
```

Sometimes that's useful because you have both single and double quotes in a string you're selecting for.

Comment: Welcome to regex. I did say "alternatively" because I agree, it does make it complex but you can't escape escaping.